# a:hover black outline around words

Tags: css, hover

I'm having a hard time figuring out what I did wrong.  When I hover, over Contact, there's a nice grey background with a blue border on the left, but there's a small black background surrounding the word Contact and I don't know how to remove that.

```
ul li:hover {
background: #c7c3c3;
border-radius: 5px;
border-left: 10px solid #16c9ff;
text-transform: uppercase;
```

}

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="new1.css"/>
    <title>Sawdust &amp Splinters</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div></div>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Photography</li>
                <li>Woodworking</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <div>
        <img src="front2.jpg"/>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**** CSS ****

```
* {
background-color: black;
}
div {
     max-width: 800px;
     margin: 0 auto; 
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
ul li {
    font-family: Maiandra GD;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding: 10px;

}

ul li:hover {
    background: #c7c3c3;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-left: 10px solid #16c9ff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:link {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}


div img {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}


#ss {
    font-family: Maiandra GD;
    font-size: 4em;
    text-align: center;

 }
```

Comment: can you put html also ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated css

```
* {
    background-color: black;
}

div {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

ul li {
    font-family: Maiandra GD;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}

ul li:hover {
    background: #c7c3c3;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-left: 10px solid #16c9ff;
}

ul li:hover .link {
    background: #c7c3c3;
    background: #c7c3c3;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:link {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

div img {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#ss {
    font-family: Maiandra GD;
    font-size: 4em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

******HTML******

```
<div></div>
<div>
   <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Photography</li>
      <li>Woodworking</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>
         <a class="link" href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div><img src="front2.jpg"></div>
```